# Getting garbled command line responses when querying webHDFS via CURL

Tags: hadoop, curl, hdfs, kerberos

I am getting the following output when trying to write a file into a kerberized HDFS:

[image]

I get the same output when trying to read from the HDFS as well:

[image]

Is it an error? If so, how do I fix it? The files I intend to read or write are not being read or written with these commands.

Comment: This is likely the encoding of your terminal that's the issue

Comment: You are trying to curl a binary file. In your case it's the png file. You must redirect your output to some file like `curl http://blah.com/file.png >file.png` if you don't want it just use `wget`. Curl outputs the contents of queried urls into the STDOUT. Cheers.